# Parentheses in .sorted(by: ) method

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array for example:

```
let myArray = [12,123,412,412,4,124,32]
```

And i want it sorted in ascending way, i create a function for it

```
func sortedAscending(_ i: Int , _ j: Int) -> Bool{ return i < j }
```

Then i create variable for storing new sorted array

```
let newSorted = myArray.sorted(by : sortedAscending())
```

Right here compiler gives me error like: *error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments*
When i delete parentheses it works fine. Can anyone explain why i should call a function sortedAscending without parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because when you pass `sortedAscending` without parentheses, you are passing the closure *itself* as a parameter. This is what you want to do, in fact, because you are telling `sorted(by:)` to use the passed-in closure to do its sorting.

By contrast, if you add the parentheses to `sortedAscending()`, you are telling the compiler to *execute* the closure first, and then pass the *result* of that to `sorted(by:)`. If `sortedAscending()` returns another closure that takes two `Int`s, this can work, but in your case, `sortedAscending()` just returns a `Bool`, and `sorted(by:)` can't take a `Bool` as an argument. In addition, the attempt to call `sortedAscending()` fails, because it requires two `Int` parameters, and you didn't provide any.

The error message, of course, is completely misleading, making it sound like the error is something totally different from what it actually is, because Swift.

Answer (score 2):

The `sorted(by:)` function expects a closure as the argument. By adding the parentheses after `sortedAscending`, you are actually trying to call the `sortedAscending` function (with no parameters) and pass the return value of the `sortedAscending` function as the argument to `sorted(by:)`.

By eliminating the parentheses, you properly pass the function as the closure argument.

But you don't need a function. Just do:

```
let newSorted = myArray.sorted { $0 < $1 }
```